# Как объединить 2 запроса INSERT в 2 таблицы?

Tags: postgresql

Есть 2 таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
        id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        name TEXT NOT NULL,
        login TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
        password TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
        email TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
        create_date Timestamp,
        role INTEGER NOT NULL,
        address INTEGER NOT NULL,
        FOREIGN KEY (role) references roles(id),
        FOREIGN KEY (address) references address(id)
);

CREATE TABLE address (
        id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        country TEXT NOT NULL,
        city TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

Пример вставки нового пользователя:

```
insert into address(id, country, city) 
values (default, 'rus', 'spb') returning id;

insert into users (id, name, login, password, email, create_date, role, address)
values (default, 'pavel1', '2', '2', 'I@mail.world2', now()::timestamp, '1', /*вставляю id адреса полученое из предыдущего запроса*/);
```

Как сделать эту вставку одним запросом? Я пытался сделать так:

```
insert into users (id, name, login, password, email, create_date, role, address)
values (default, 'pavel1', '2', '2', 'I@mail.world2', now()::timestamp, '1',

(insert into address(id, country, city) values (default, 'rus', 'spb') returning id)

);
```

Но не получилось(. Подскажите пожалуйста как их объединить?

Comment: Может триггерную функцию использовать?

Comment: @GlWhitefoot что-то сложно похоже что тригеры отдельная большая тема. А как-то попроще нельзя?

Comment: Они хоть и сложнее чем в мускл , но довольно просты. Думаю лучше использовать их, плюс на удаление и обновление можно повесить свои действия. Хотя подождем, может кто что другое предложит.

Comment: @GlWhitefoot я вот смотрю что тригеры не принимают параметры а мне надо чтобы два INSERTта связать.

Comment: Все они могут, если до завтра не напишут вам ответ , то приведу пример.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я вас немного обманул. Не триггерная функция, а просто функция (процедура). Вот так можно в вашем случае сделать:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION double_insert(
    country character varying,
    city character varying,
    name character varying,
    login character varying,
    password character varying,
    email character varying,
    role integer,
    address character varying)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    country ALIAS FOR $1; 
    city ALIAS FOR $2; 
    name ALIAS FOR $3; 
    login ALIAS FOR $4; 
    password ALIAS FOR $5; 
    email ALIAS FOR $6; 
    role ALIAS FOR $7; 
    address ALIAS FOR $8; 
    addrid integer;
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO "address"("country", "city") VALUES (country, city) RETURNING "id" INTO addrid;
    INSERT INTO users ("name", "login", "password", "email", "create_date", "role", "address") VALUES (name,login, password, email, now()::timestamp, role, addrid) ;

END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Вызываем так:

```
select double_insert('aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 1, 'aaa')
```